# JUnit fails but no tests report as failing

Tags: java, ant, junit

I am running JUnit tests using Ant on the command line on Windows XP.

On some runs, midway through running all of the tests, I will get a `BUILD FAILED` message pointing at a specific test class, but all of the tests in that class are reported as having passed both in the console output and in the XML file.

The class contains no non-determinism and should not have any side-effects.  There is no reason for it to be running out of memory either.

What could cause these strange build failures?

---

**Update**:

I doubt this will be helpful, but here is the end of the run when it fails (modified directory and package names for anonymity):

```
C:\proj\er20\rr> ant clean build test

<snip/>

[junit] Running com.example.PathUTest
[junit] Tests run: 6, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Time elapsed: 7.5 sec

BUILD FAILED
C:\proj\er20\common\build.xml:385: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\proj\er20\rr\build.xml:58: Test com.example.PathUTest failed
```

---

**Update 2**:

I have finally managed to get the failure to happen with -verbose enabled.  Here is the stacktrace (copied by hand):

```
BUILD FAILED
C:\proj\er20\common\build.xml:385: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\proj\er20\rr\build.xml:58: Test com.example.PathUTest failed
    at org.apache.tools.ant.ProjectHelper.addLocationToBuildException(ProjectHelper.java:541)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:418)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.CallTarget.execute(CallTarget.java:105)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:288)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:105)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:357)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:385)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1329)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1298)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1181)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:698)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:199)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:257)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:104)
Caused by: C:\proj\er20\rr\build.xml:58: Test com.example.PathUTest failed
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optionl.junit.JUnitTask.actOnTestResult(JUnitTask.java:1712)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optionl.junit.JUnitTask.execute(JUnitTask.java:820)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optionl.junit.JUnitTask.executeOrQueue(JUnitTask.java:1657)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optionl.junit.JUnitTask.execute(JUnitTask.java:764)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:288)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:105)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:357)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:385)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1329)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.SingleCheckExecutor.executeTargets(SingleCheckExecutor.java:38)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:416)
    ... 17 more
--- Nested Exception ---
C:\proj\er20\rr\build.xml:58 Test com.example.PathUTest failed
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optionl.junit.JUnitTask.actOnTestResult(JUnitTask.java:1712)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optionl.junit.JUnitTask.execute(JUnitTask.java:820)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optionl.junit.JUnitTask.executeOrQueue(JUnitTask.java:1657)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optionl.junit.JUnitTask.execute(JUnitTask.java:764)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:288)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:105)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:357)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.perform(Target.java:385)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1329)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.SingleCheckExecutor.executeTargets(SingleCheckExecutor.java:38)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:416)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.tskdefs.CallTarget.execute(CallTarget.java:105)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:288)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Source Unknown)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:105)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:357)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:385)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1329)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1298)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1181)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:698)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:199)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:257)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:104)

Total time: 1 minute 27 seconds
```

And here is the relevant Ant target:

```
<target name="test">
    <taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antcontrib.properties">
        <classpath>
            <pathelement location="../buildsupport/lib/ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar"/>
        </classpath>
    </taskdef>

    <!-- line 58 is the next line -->
    <junit printsummary="yes" fork="yes" haltonfailure="yes" dir="${test-dir}" showoutput="yes">
        <jvmarg value="-Xmx10200M"/>
        <jvmarg value="-Xms600M"/>
        <jvmarg value="-server"/>
        <jvmarg value="-Dlog4j.configuration=file:log4j.xml"/>
        <jvmarg value="-XX:CompileCommand=exclude,com.example.GtaCore,expandLabel"/>
        <env key="LD_LIBRARY_PATH" path="${env.LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:${test-dir}/native_lib"/>
        <jvmarg value="-Djava.library.path=./native_lib"/>
        <formatter type="xml"/>
        <classpath>
            <!-- classpath items -->
        </classpath>
        <batchtest>
            <fileset includes="**/*Test.class" excludes="**/*$$*.class"/>
        </batchtest>
    </junit>

    <junitreport>
        <!-- config -->
    </junitreport>
    <echo> finished suite</echo>
</target>
```

---

**Probable Cause and Solution**

We discovered that deep down within code that we were calling, an error debugging GUI was being displayed which ran in another thread.  Since disabling the display of this GUI, we have not seen this issue again.

Comment: An exception thrown in the teardown?

Comment: Post a chunk of the logged errors.

Comment: Are these *build* failures or *test* failures you're seeing?

Comment: @Argyle That's the strange thing: there are no errors anywhere, just the test BUILD FAILED and an Ant stacktrace pointing at one of my test classes.

Comment: @LaurenceGonsalves They are build failures.  No tests are reporting as failed.

Comment: @JensSchauder I don't have any teardown/@ After/@ AfterClass method in any of my tests.  Would an exception in @ BeforeClass or @ Before not leave any error message and let JUnit think the tests passed?

Comment: Assuming that you've built your code with the debugging symbols, the stack trace should point at a particular line in your test file.  What's happening on the specified line?

Comment: @Argyle There is no stacktrace produced.  Just and telling us what line in the build.xml the build failed on.  The line is, not surprisingly, the line that runs JUnit.  There is no indication that the failure is coming from one of the tests.

Comment: Could it be you didn't clean, and your class building fails, but tests are still a) run on the classes last time they compiled or b) being reported from an old junit report?

Comment: @Miquel I am running clean prior to building and testing.

Comment: Try running ant with the "-verbose" flag.  If you're lucky, this might provide a few more details.

Comment: Please post content of 'C:\proj\er20\rr\build.xml' , lines 58 and related.

Comment: @EJK I tried about 40 times yesterday, both with and without -verbose, to reproduce the situation, but was unsuccessful.  A coworker spent a few hours trying to look into it and thinks it is a race condition between my code (single threaded) and JUnit when my code throws an exception.  We're going to look into that more today.

Comment: Nice you posted this detailed info. I was curious on the code that caused trouble, but to see it I would need the exact ant version you use. What is it? Looks like it is some old one.

Comment: @jarekczek We are still using Ant 1.7.0.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe in rr\build.xml (you have 2 build files) at line 58 there is

```
<fail message="Test com.example.PathUTest failed"/>
```

Comment: Nope.  Line 58 is the line that the junit task is on that is failing.  Nowhere in any of our build.xml's is there a <fail/> task.